# How can I guarantee that a class that implements an interface also extends a class?

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

I have this code:

```
public class Animate {} // external api <--------------

public class Cat extends Animate {} // written by me

public interface Walks {} // also written by me
```

How can I enforce that if something walks it has to be animate?

Comment: Why can you implement Walks in Animate itself?

Comment: @AbishekManoharan nope

Comment: @AlexandruSeverin nope

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An abstract class can extend a class, and this is one of the rare situations where it could be useful.

```
abstract class AnimatedAbstractWalker extends Animate {

    // class gets concrete methods from Animate

    // and any abstract walk methods you want to add
    // (this replaces the Walk interface)
}

class Cat extends AnimatedAbstractWalker {
    // inherits standard animation implementation
    // you must implement walking like a cat
}

class Dog extends AnimatedAbstractWalker {
    // inherits standard animation implementation
    // you must implement walking like a dog
}
```

Comment: you meant `abstract class AnimatedWalker extends Animate implements Walks` ??

Comment: To finalize this, your abstract AnimatedWalker class should implement the Walks interface.

Comment: nice! I will try this.

Comment: @AbishekManoharan If you have the interface Walks then you always leave open the possibility that someone will implement a class that implements Walks but does not extend AnimatedWalker. I believe what is suggested here is that you do not have a separate interface Walks.

Comment: @DJClayworth, Oh right... So it's more like `abstract class Walks extends Animate {}`... That's the best solution for this problem I guess..

Comment: @DJClayworth yes, the abstract class is replacing the interface. If it implemented the interface, it would not satisfy OP's needs. Leaving the abstract methods (of the interface) abstract (in the abstract class) still allows clients to implement the `walk` logic. I guess I will change the name to `AnimatedAbstractWalker`.

Comment: @gurghet If you want to allow different classes to implement walking differently, this solution will allow that. I am assuming that is what you want, since you made `Walks` an interface. The solution chosen removes the "interfacey" parts of `Walks` since only one concrete class is implementing it, and `Cat` and all other siblings of cat now cannot implement walking themselves.

Comment: I'll try both and reconsider my choice if necessary!

Comment: I’ll use the orther solution but *technically* your answer is correct.

Answer (score 3):

Make a class that extends Animate, has no extra methods and implements Walks (It would be identical to Animate, but it would be yours)

```
public class MyAnimate extends Animate implements Walks{} // your own Animate

public class Cat extends MyAnimate {}
```

Comment: With this solution, all animals will walk the same. What if you want a dog to walk differently than a cat?

Comment: @The111  We can agree that your answer fits that specific requirement and mine doesn't.

Comment: I will use this solution, but the other answer is "more correctly" answering to my precise question

Comment: @AlexandruSeverin your answer may fit his actual use case better though. I think both answers are appropriate for different use cases. If you only want to implement walk once for all animated things, but you **also** want to leave it as an interface so clients in a totally different realm can implement it, then I think your solution would be better for that.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot.

An interface just defines an API and does not enforce an implementation.

If you want that something both implements an interface and extends an implementation, just create an abstract base class doing both and extend from there :

```
public class WalkingAnimate extends Animate implements Walks {
    public abstract ... // abstracts methods from Walks 
}

public class Cat extends WalkingAnimate {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since class `Animate` is external you can't change it, but you can subclass it in your code:

```
public abstract class AnimatedWalk extends Animate implements Walk {}
```

In consequence, each class that inherits from your newly created `AnimatedWalk` is a `Animate` and has to implement `Walk`

```
public class Cat extends AnimatedWalk { ... }
```

Comment: Except that you have to implement all the methods in `Walk` in your `AnimatedWalk` class, which you may not be able to do so...

Comment: actually it's better to make class `AnimatedWalk` abstract